# How can I exclude elements from the function effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this page when the user click "Show Image" button, a random image appear. that's good. I need the script only affect this image.

The problem is the header image disappear too, and I need to keep all other images displayed.
I need a solution

Code here:
https://codepen.io/Haitham1000/pen/aXjYzz

```
function display_random_image() 
{
var theImages = [{
src: "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3691/11268502654_f28f05966c_m.jpg",
width: "240",
height: "160"
}, {
src: "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/33/45336904_1aef569b30_n.jpg",
width: "320",
height: "195"
}, {
src: "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5211/5384592886_80a512e2c9.jpg",
width: "500",
height: "343"
}];

var preBuffer = [];
for (var i = 0, j = theImages.length; i < j; i++) {
preBuffer[i] = new Image();
preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i].src;
preBuffer[i].width = theImages[i].width;
preBuffer[i].height = theImages[i].height;
}

// create random image number
function getRandomInt(min,max) 
{
//  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

imn = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
return preBuffer[imn];
}  

// 0 is first image,   preBuffer.length - 1) is  last image

var newImage = getRandomInt(0, preBuffer.length - 1);

// remove the previous images
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var l = images.length;
for (var p = 0; p < l; p++) {
images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
}
// display the image  
var targetContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
targetContainer[0].appendChild(newImage);
}
```

Comment: Your codepen is over 10k lines of code. Please provide a [mcve] which reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `container` is the only place where there will be images you want to remove (for example, the previous image), you can iterate over just the images it contains, rather than all images in the document.  For example:

```
// remove the previous images
var targetContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
var images = targetContainer.getElementsByTagName('img');
var l = images.length;
for (var p = 0; p < l; p++) {
    images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
}
// display the image
targetContainer.appendChild(newImage);
```

Note that `var targetContainer` was moved to the top, that the `[0]` was added to it, and that `images` is now coming from `targetContainer.getElementsByTagName`.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGOoam)

Answer (score 0):

You are finding and then looping over every image on the page to remove it. Instead of `var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');` try getting images in the **container** and then replace them.

```
function display_random_image() {
    ....
    var newImage = getRandomInt(0, preBuffer.length - 1);

    //GET THE CONTAINER FIRST
    var targetContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
    //FIND THE IMAGES IN CONTAINER ONLY
    var images = targetContainer.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var l = images.length;
    for (var p = 0; p < l; p++) {
        images[0].remove();
    }
    // display the image
    targetContainer.appendChild(newImage);
}
```